# Convert Data format using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I need to convert date format into  **NEW_FORMAT** date format. I want to show like this **June 28,2016**  ,but its showing **January** irrespective of any month number I pass. Please check where I am missing..

```
public class DateClass {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-mm-dd";
            final String NEW_FORMAT = "MMMM dd,yyyy";

            String oldDateString = "2016-06-28";
            String newDateString;

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
            Date d;
            try {
                d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
                sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
                newDateString = sdf.format(d);
                System.out.println(""+newDateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got it.Thanx to all... final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-mm-dd"; should be replaced with final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `OLD_FORMAT` is wrong, it should be `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. Here small `m` should be replaced by capital `M`, since small `m` represents minutes and `M` represents month of year, and while parsing using `OLD_FORMAT`, date is getting parsed wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `mm` in `OLD_FORMAT` which stands for minute. You want to have `MM` which stands for month.

Therefore your `OLD_FORMAT` should be `yyyy-MM-dd`.

The minute is set to `0` in your case therefore the month is January.

Answer (score 2):

In java, **mm** represents as minuets and **MM** represents as Month, so you have to change your code as

```
  final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  final String NEW_FORMAT = "MMMM dd,yyyy";

  String oldDateString = "2016-06-28";
```

Answer (score 2):

change this one

```
 final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-mm-dd";
```

to

```
 final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```